# How can I test if I have all the right credentials with php-opencloud sdk?

Tags: php, api, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

Here is my code for now:

```
$cloud = new Rackspace('https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/', $php_cloudconfig['credentials']);
$array_creds = getCredentials();
$cloud->ImportCredentials($array_creds);

$array_creds = $cloud->ExportCredentials();
setCredentials($array_creds['authorization_token'], $array_creds['expiration'], $array_creds['tenant_id'], $array_creds['service_catalog']);

function getCredentials() {
    $sql_get_credential = "SELECT * FROM cloud_apiconnection";
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql_get_credential);
    return $q->execute();
}

function setCredentials($authorization_token, $expiration, $tenant_id, $service_catalog)     {
    $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO cloud_apiconnection (authorization_token, expiration, tenant_id, service_catalog) VALUES (:authorization_token, :expiration, :tenant_id, :service_catalog)";
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql_insert);
    $q->execute(array(':authorization_token' => $authorization_token, ':expiration' => $expiration, ':tenant_id' => $tenant_id, ':service_catalog' => $service_catalog));
}
```

Is there a way to detect if the credentials were updated in: $cloud->ImportCredentials($array_creds); ?

I am wandering because I don't want to write to the DB if I don't need to.

Also is this the best strategy for managing my connection to RackSpace API?

Comment: Can I use PHP-OpenCloud for my OpenStack cloud deplyed locally on single machine? or it is only for RackSpace cloud?

Comment: It works with OpenStack so it should work on your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a good strategy for maintaining a persistent session, because you're re-using an existing token ID. The only other suggestion is to cache your credentials in a local file, rather than making an MySQL transaction. You don't really need to store your tenant ID and service catalog because these are easily retrievable through the software layer.

To check the validity an existing token, I'd do this:

```
$connection = new Rackspace(...);

// Import existing credentials
$credentials = getCredentials();
$connection->importCredentials($credentials);

// Authenticate against the API to make sure your token is still valid
$connection->authenticate();

// Compare result
$newCredentials = $connection->exportCredentials();

if ($newCredentials['authorization_token'] != $credentials['authorization_token']) {
   // You know it's been updated, so save new ones
   setCredentials();
}
```

All the `authenticate()` method does is execute a request against the Rackspace API; and based on the results, it's effectively letting you know whether your existing stuff is still valid. When other methods call `authenticate()`, they usually do another check beforehand: they check the expiry value (i.e. not in the past). You could implement the same thing they do (to find out whether credentials need to be refreshed and saved):

```
if (time() > ($credentials['expiration'] - RAXSDK_FUDGE)) {
   // They're old, you need to call authenticate()
} else {
   // They seem to be still valid. Sweet!
}
```

By the way, we've recently changed this functionality so that `exportCredentials()` makes a call to `authenticate()` - so this would mean you wouldn't need to call it yourself. But for your current version it's worth leaving it in.

Does that answer everything?

Comment: I though it was "importCredentials" that checked if the token was still valid and authenticate try to get a new token.

Comment: All `importCredentials` does is import values (from an array) into the connection object - nothing else happens. In order to check whether credentials are truly valid, you will need to call `authenticate` which makes a request against the API. The API will return back either the existing token (if it's valid) or issue another one. The only test the _PHP library_ can do is a basic check on the expiry value.

Comment: I do have another question. What is the best way to store the catalog in the DB. (I have decided to use sqlite3 to store the token, expiration, tenant, catalog).

Comment: I would have one entry in a `credentials` table that contains `token` and `expiration` - you don't need anything else. When you update, you will need to UPDATE the existing record rather than INSERTing a new, effectively duplicate, record. I'd also index for performance.

Comment: Got it working. I had to change the permission rights of the sqlite3 file and the folder that contained it. So I don't need to store the catalog. But what about the tenant id? And yes I change my SQL so that it does a UPDATE and not a INSERT. Do I really need to index? I am using a PRIMARY KEY with the id. I just say use the id equal to 1. Would it really change anything if I use indexing with SQLite and the setup I have?

Comment: It's best practice to index for large data sets so that depends on the number of records in the table. You'll have to determine if you want to take the performance hit of doing a full table scan each time you run a select/update query.